# python-eve hook after document is inserted

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, eve

I understand we have a on_insert_resources event that is triggered once a post is sent to python-eve, but this is before the document is saved onto mongodb, is it possible to get a hook after the document is saved? (I need to populate some of the field according to it ID that is generated by mongodb) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Post-Request hooks](http://python-eve.org/features.html#post-request-event-hooks) would do the trick for you. Something like so:

```
>>> def update_docs(resource, request, payload):
...     """ do your stuff here """
...     pass

>>> app = Eve()

>>> app.on_post_POST += udpate_docs
>>> app.run()
```

`payload` contains the response stream which includes all the document unique ids and the other metatags (`_etag`, etc.)

Comment: If you need `_ìd`, you have to use an `on_inserted`hook.